# power failure - 2b1.1

Tags: pi-2, boot, power-light

1. a few weeks ago, my pi 2b failed to detect usb wireless adapter.
2. yesterday, red power indicator flashed sporadically, but booted.
3. today, it failed to boot.
4. checked connections, tried different power supplies and different usb cables. (power supply and cables ok on pi3)
5. can it be fixed or is it time to trash it?

Comment: Have you tried new SD Card?

Comment: Very new, but will try another. Pi was in an enclosure behind a 5x7 touch screen. Seemed to run hotter than the Pi-4

Comment: Running hotter than a Pi 4 doesn't sound good.  So it currently fails to boot with any SD card, including one with a fresh image of Raspberry Pi OS?  What currently happens with the lights on startup - the number of flashes of the red light is important.  Add that info to the question.  Also if possible compare the behaviour with another Raspberry Pi 2 if you have one.